# Image alignment and size are changing during recompose in lazyRow. Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, image, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, coil

All I want is to create an image with a certain height. Automatically changing the width without breaking the width/height ratio of the image I took from the url.Then align it to start. When i run this code first images which shown in screen align to right. After scroll images aligned correctly to the left. And when i come back to first they are correct too. What is the reason why the images that appears first is not aligned to the left? I am using implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.2.2")
[image: The left is one of the first that shown in screen. and the right is shown when i scroll]

```
  LazyRow(
            modifier = Modifier

                .wrapContentHeight()
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            items(favoriteBooks.size, key = { index ->
                favoriteBooks[index].id
            }) {


            val  painter = remember {
                mutableStateOf<AsyncImagePainter?>(null)
            }
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .wrapContentWidth()
                        .wrapContentHeight()
                        .padding(end = 16.dp)
                        .border(2.dp, color = Color.Magenta),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start
                ) {

                    painter.value = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
                        model = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
                            .data(
                                if (favoriteBooks.get(it).thumbnail.isNullOrEmpty())
                                    R.drawable.placeholder
                                else
                                    favoriteBooks.get(it).thumbnail
                            )
                            .crossfade(true)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                            //.transformations(RoundedCornersTransformation(1f))
                            .size(Size.ORIGINAL)
                            .build()
                    )
                    Image(
                        painter = painter.value as AsyncImagePainter,
                        contentDescription = null,
                        contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight,
                        alignment =Alignment.BottomStart,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxHeight(0.3f)
                            .aspectRatio(1f)
                            .width(IntrinsicSize.Min)
                        //.wrapContentWidth()
                    )



                    Text(text = favoriteBooks[it].categories[0], color = Color.Green)
                    Text(text = favoriteBooks[it].title, color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface)
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue might be related to how the `LazyRow` is initialized when the images are first loaded. There could be a couple of reasons why the alignment doesn't work as expected initially:

- The `LazyRow` might not have enough information about the item widths during the first rendering pass, causing the initial alignment to be incorrect.
- The `AsyncImagePainter` might not be ready with the image data when the layout is first drawn, causing misalignment.

To fix this issue, you can try using the `onSizeChanged` modifier to force a recomposition once the image size is known. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
Image(
    painter = painter.value as AsyncImagePainter,
    contentDescription = null,
    contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight,
    alignment = Alignment.BottomStart,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxHeight(0.3f)
        .aspectRatio(1f)
        .width(IntrinsicSize.Min)
        .onSizeChanged { size ->
            if (size.width > 0) {
                painter.value?.requestRedraw()
            }
        }
)
```

Comment: I couldn't find the requestRedraw  can you tell me which version of compose ui you are using?

Comment: @serlok17 - There are several indicators this answer was generated by ChatGPT.